# FileStream/StreamWriter in .NET Core 1.1 have no Close() method

Tags: c#, stream, .net-core, dispose

I'm using .net core 1.1, previously when I was with .net framework, I usually call `Close()` on `FileStream` or any Stream after I finished the stream operations, but the `FileStream` class in .net core 1.1 doesn't have Close method, I found `Dispose()` but don't know if it's the equivalent. Anyone care to let me know the right way to correctly close with the new `FileStream/StreamWriter` class in .net core?

Comment: They used .NETCore to correct some well-meant design decisions in the full framework that did not pan out well.  Like the Stream class having two methods that do the exact same thing, Dispose and Close.  Sound design on paper, but baffling to many programmers who can't decide which one is "better".

Comment: Like Hans stated, you can safely use `Dispose` instead. Please accept an answer below to end the discussion. Microsoft has added `Close` back in upcoming .NET Standard 2.0, which should be part of .NET Core 1.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implementing `IDisposable` means that you can use a `using` statement, which will implicitly call the `Dispose()` method, thus closing the stream.

Use

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
{
    // your logic here
} // here Dispose() is called implicitly and the stream is closed
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) or build your own [Dispose Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx).

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Running into this issue, trying to keep legacy code intact, another option would be to write an extension method.

```
public static class FileStreamExtension
{
    public static void Close(this FileStream reader)
    {
        reader.Dispose();
    }
}
```